# Perl print matched regex string

Tags: regex, string, perl

The following perl code only gives back true or false (1 & 0)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string;

$string ="interface Ethernet1/20
  shutdown";

my $test = $string =~ m/^.+$(?=\s+shutdown)/mg;
print "'$test'\n";
```

I get back a 1.
But how can I get back the matched string 'interface Ethernet1/20' ?
Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply give it list context:

```
my ($test) = $string =~ m/^.+$(?=\s+shutdown)/mg;
```

The concept of evaluation context (list vs scalar) is fundamental to Perl programming, so it may be time to review some tutorials and/or a reference manual.